# Firebase: Unable to Import a large json from Forge

Tags: firebase

I have a 32mb backup of my data from another firebase app. I want to import it to a new firebase app. But it fails and in dev console, I see this error:

FIREBASE INTERNAL ERROR: Server Error: ClientId[49013482]:ErrorId[812]: Write too large

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [firebase-import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import)? That may help.

Comment: Hey thanks! 
Let me try this one. I was thinking of making my own script to do what firebase-import does I guess.